# can anyone find out why is the tree not linking

Tags: c

i am writing a code to create a binary tree but something is going wrong i tried to debug but could not find can anyone find it.

code that i have tried is as follow..

header files are..

```
#include< stdio.h>
#include< stdlib.h>
```

structure is..

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}
```

other declaration..

```
*head,*p=NULL;
int count=0;
```

`create()` function is..

```
void create(int m) {
    if(count==0)
    {
        p=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        p->data=m;
        p->left=NULL;
        p->right=NULL;
        head=p;
        count++;
    }  
    else {
        p=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        p->data=m;
        p->left=NULL;
        p->right=NULL;
    }
}
```

main function is..

```
int main()
{
    int n,i,m;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&m);
        if(i==0) {create(m);}

        if(i>0) {
            while(1) {
                if(m < p->data) 
                    p=p->left;
                else
                    p=p->right;

                if(p==NULL) 
                {
                    create(m);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        p=head;
    }

    printf("%d",p->left->data); //printing the data
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think, when i = 1, then count is also 1,

```
if(m<p->data)
{
    p=p->left;
}
```

what will be happened when **p->left** is a **null**? Now **p** is a null pointer, right? Then you did this...

```
if(p==NULL)
{
    create(m);
    break;
}
```

Lets see, what is happening in **create(m)**. Now in **create()** else portion will work.

```
else
{
    p=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->data=m;
    p->left=NULL;
    p->right=NULL;
}
```

It is also OK. Now you have a child of head. Reference of this child is in **p**. Right? But the mistake which you have done is,

```
p=head;
```

That means, what have you done is gone. Now there is no reference of child of head. p is keeping reference of head. See, **head->left** or **head->right** is always **NULL** whatever you keep in **p**. So you have to create a node where you find a **NULL**, not in **p**. It is not giving you any result.

Hope, it will help you. :)